# Handle dynamic Xpath in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium I need to handle the XPath which is being dynamic on every next page.

Here, I am trying to click on the same element at every page.

Below are the Xpath of the same Web-element with the only difference with div[] tag

Page 1:

```
.//*[@id='PageScrollArea']/div/div/div[4]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/img
```

Page 2:

```
.//*[@id='PageScrollArea']/div/div/div[4]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/img
```

Page 3:

```
.//*[@id='PageScrollArea']/div/div/div[4]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/img
```

I am not sure how to handle this dynamic behavior of div[] tag:

```
.... /div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/img
.... /div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/img
.... /div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/img
.... /div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/img
```

Comment: there's no way to handle dynamic path in this case, that's why you should use relative path like:

    //parent//child-few-layers-below

Answer (score 0):

there's no way to handle dynamic path in this case, that's why you should use relative path like:

```
//parent//child-few-layers-below
```

please provide html of searched element and we'll help to write path